# Difference between offensichtlich and ersichtlich

Tags: difference, german-to-english

I checked multiple dictionaries but couldn't find any significant difference.

Can they be used interchangeably ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

"Ersichtlich" basically means that something is visible (literally or figuratively). There's little to no judgement in the subtext. The word is often used in phrases like "ohne ersichtlichen Grund", "with no discernible reason".

> Mein Antrag wurde ohne ersichtlichen Grund abgelehnt.

On the other hand, "offensichtlich" has a vibe of "hey, don't try to tell me that you couldn't have seen that, it has been obvious". So there's a bit of a judgment involved. An example might be

> Mein Antrag wurde aus offensichtlichen Gründen abgelehnt. Schließlich habe ich den Bürgermeister letzte Woche scharf kritisiert.

Comment: Im zweiten Beispiel tendiert die "angestrebte Bedeutung" zu _fadenscheinig_. Vielleicht ist gemeint: _Mein Antrag wurde offensichtlich nur deswegen abgelehnt, weil ..._ - _offensichtliche Gründe_ ist für mich 'irgendwie schief', vermutlich weil '_offensichtlich_ meist adverbial benutzt wird.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very small difference, but that difference is the reason why they are **sinnverwandt** but no synonyms.

Synonyms of *offensichtlich* would be *offenbar* or *eindeutig*.

You can put *offensichtlich* in all places you can put *ersichtlich*, but you can't put *ersichtlich* in all places you put *offensichtlich*.

*Ersichtlich* can mean it is obvious to know.

*Offensichtlich* can mean it is obvious to know OR obvious to happen.

Therefore you can use either one in this sentence:

> Die Lösung ist 42, das ist doch ersichtlich
> Die Lösung ist 42, das ist doch offensichtlich

But you can't use both in this one:

> Offensichtlich regnet es gleich.

This sounds just wrong:

> Ersichtlich regnet es gleich.

But there is a hack. Just use *ersichtlicher Weise* if you mean something to happen, that would work:

> Ersichtlicher Weise regnet es gleich